# Facebook api status updates and the 'share' link

Tags: api, facebook, hyperlink

I have been updating status messages from my site to my clients facebook pages or fan pages using the PHP sdk like this

```
$facebook = new Facebook('facebookApiKey', 'facebookAppSecret'); 
$facebook->api_client->users_setStatus($statusText, $facebookUid);
```

When the status is posted and it shows up in my news feeds, I only have an options to 'Comment' or 'Like' that post, but not to 'Share' it like other updates do http://grab.by/6Juz.

I'm not sure if that is even possible with users_setStatus? is there anything I need to change in my canvas page to allow this link to show up? is there any other api call that I need to use before/after the status update to enable  this link?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is old but as i was looking for this i thought i would post it any way.
check out: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=90079

I am using a c# library for the graph api so you will need to make some adaptions:

```
public void PublishWithAction(string text, string actionName, string actionLink, long? targetID )
    {
        client.Post((targetID.HasValue ? targetID.Value.ToString() : "me") + "/feed", new Dictionary<String, Object> { 
            { "message", text },
            { "actions", new List<Object>{new {name=actionName,link=actionLink}}},
        });
    }
```

if you use `"share"` as the action name and `"http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<ShareURL>"` as the action link you get close to the facebook share option.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Unfortunately, since the ajax link that FB implements requires the ID of the post, which isn't available until after the post is created, we can't easily fake the full featured one. Until FB allows either a wildcard string replace on submitted items, or perhaps just enables an auto action share item, this is probably the best we can do.